# Display to-do comments in TFS build log

Tags: c#, resharper, tfsbuild

I would like to display all the to-do comments of the source code in the result of the TFS build, just like the warnings. I am currently using Resharper to manually list the to-do items.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you.